# Boost TCP async_receive_some doesn't read second time

Tags: c++, asynchronous, tcp, boost-asio

I try to have an TCP-Server, which is reading Data, processing them and send them back. After that it shall wait for new Data. My Problem is, that the server works fine for the first time data is sent. At the second time, the program stays in the `run_one()`-loop.

```cpp
size_t m_lengthReceive;
io_service m_ioService;
std::vector<unsigned char> m_vectorBuffer;
unsigned char m_bufferReceive[128];


void SyncServer::initialize(){      
        m_acceptor = shared_ptr<tcp::acceptor>(
                new tcp::acceptor(m_ioService,
                        tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_port)));

        m_acceptor->set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        m_sock = shared_ptr<tcp::socket>(new tcp::socket(m_ioService));

        m_acceptor->accept(*m_sock, m_ec);
}

void SyncServer::tcpReceiveVector(){
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        m_sock->async_read_some(buffer(m_bufferReceive),
                boost::bind(&SyncServer::tcpReceiveHandler, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        do{
            m_ioService.run_one();
        }while(m_lengthReceive == 0);
}


void SyncServer::tcpReceiveHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
        size_t size){
    if(size > 0 && !ec){
        m_sock->cancel();
        m_lengthReceive = size;
        m_vectorBuffer.resize(m_lengthReceive);
        int i = 0;
        for(std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator it = m_vectorBuffer.begin();
                it != m_vectorBuffer.end(); ++it){
            *it = m_bufferReceive[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }else{
        m_lengthReceive = 0;
        m_sock->async_read_some(buffer(m_bufferReceive),
                boost::bind(&SyncServer::tcpReceiveHandler, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}

std::vector<unsigned char> SyncServer::getVectorBuffer(){
    return m_vectorBuffer;
}

void SyncServer::openConnection(){
    if(!m_sock->is_open())
        m_sock->open(tcp::v4());
    m_lengthReceive = 0;
}

void SyncServer::closeConnection(){
    m_sock->close();

}

main(){
    m_tcpServer = shared_ptr<SyncServer>(new SyncServer(m_tcpPort));
    m_tcpServer->initialize();
    while(1){
        m_tcpServer->openConnection();
        m_tcpServer->tcpReceiveVector();
        vector = m_tcpServer->getVectorBuffer();

        //do something with vector

        m_tcpServer->tcpSend(vector); //this works fine
        m_tcpServer->closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Updated Code:

```
void SyncServer::tcpReceiveHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
        size_t size){
    if(ec){
        std::cout<< ec << std::endl;
    }else{
        if(size > 0){
            m_sock->cancel();
            m_lengthReceive = size;
            m_vectorBuffer.resize(m_lengthReceive);
            int i = 0;
            for(std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator it = m_vectorBuffer.begin();
                    it != m_vectorBuffer.end(); ++it){
                *it = m_bufferReceive[i];
                ++i;
            }
        }else{
            m_lengthReceive = 0;
            m_sock->async_read_some(buffer(m_bufferReceive),
                    boost::bind(&SyncServer::tcpReceiveHandler, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Nim answered, you also did the classical asio error. As documented here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one/overload1.html
"Subsequent calls to run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() will return immediately unless there is a prior call to reset()."

After your `.run_one` you need to call `m_ioservice.reset()` or it will never do any running again. It just returns instead of invoking any any async operations and thus `m_lengthReceive` will not change after the first time.

```
    do{
        m_ioService.run_one();
        m_ioService.reset();
    }while(m_lengthReceive == 0);
```

This is the reason people normally do not use `run_one()` but `run()` and start a new async operation within the handler of the last one. In that case the `run()` does not return and no `reset()` is required.

Comment: This solved the first problem. Now I get an Error 107 `not_connected`. Now I'll try to find out what the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: You are still not starting a new `async_receive()` after the first one finishes successfully as far as i can see. So once you receive something, you process it, set `m_lengthReceive` to something not 0 and leave the `run_one()` loop. Then you send something and close the connection without giving the client any other shot at sending you something. Basically, if you want to receive more than once, you need a `async_receive()` in the `if(size>0)` path of the handler, not only the `else`.

Comment: But I'm in a `while(1)`-loop in my main, where I start a new receive every time. Won't that have nearly the same effect?

Comment: But while you close the connection in that loop, you do not accept a new one as that is in the initialize part outside of the loop. Does it work if you move your open and close methods outside of the main loop?

Comment: When I doesn't open and close the connection in the loop, the Programm doesn't read the Data at the second time. It just uses the vector of the first reading the hole time and doesn't block. If I do the `async_read_some` in both cases, the programm returns Error 107 `not_connected` and 125 `operation_aborted`.

Comment: I added in the `openConnection()` something to accept the `m_acceptor` and now it works.

Comment: Good to hear. One last point, that does not hurt but is more of a slight misunderstanding: The line `boost::system::error_code ec;` does not do anything useful in your code. You do not use your error code afterwards. You could pass it as an argument for example to `run_one(ec)` which then would not throw on error but instead store the problem it encountered in that variable. That is the reason for the overload with `ec` wherever it exists in asio. If you want your calls to throw exceptions when something goes very wrong, then you do not need your `ec` at all and can delete that line.

Answer (score 2):

In your receive handler, you will only trigger another read if there is a problem(?)

```
void SyncServer::tcpReceiveHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
        size_t size){
    if(size > 0 && !ec){
        m_sock->cancel();
        m_lengthReceive = size;
        m_vectorBuffer.resize(m_lengthReceive);
        int i = 0;
        for(std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator it = m_vectorBuffer.begin();
                it != m_vectorBuffer.end(); ++it){
            *it = m_bufferReceive[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }else{
        m_lengthReceive = 0;
        m_sock->async_read_some(buffer(m_bufferReceive),
                boost::bind(&SyncServer::tcpReceiveHandler, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

On this callback, you need to queue the next read (normally if there are no problems, not when there is a problem!)

Comment: I've included another path now, if there is an error. But that doesn't solve the problem. There is no error thrown.